# Curious about performance difference when use gci with -filter

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Just notice performance difference between below commands. Does anybody know why ? Just curious.

```
 PS> gci -r *.txt          # this is slower
```

```
 PS> gci -r -filter *.txt  # this is faster
```

Comment: the `-Filter` parameter [as with many such PoSh cmdlets] sends the value to the target and the filter is applied THERE.  so, in your 1st example the filtering is done by PoSh after the WHOLE list is passed back to the calling code [slower] ... but the 2nd example has the filtering done by the filesystem and only the matching items are returned to the caller [faster].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented under [`-filter` Parameter.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1)

> -`Filter`
>
> Specifies a filter to qualify the Path parameter. The *[FileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_filesystem_provider?view=powershell-7)* provider is the only installed PowerShell provider that
> supports filters. ***Filters are more efficient than other parameters.
> The provider applies filter when the cmdlet gets the objects rather
> than having PowerShell filter the objects after they're retrieved. The
> filter string is passed to the .NET API to enumerate files***. The API
> only supports * and ? wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

When you use tab completion after dash (-{tab}), first parameter being suggested is `-Path` and that's where your pattern is being passed on to.

So two commands are not equivilent. The difference should be the same as between `-Include` and `-Filter`. Filter is always faster, as it taps into File System provider, instead of filtering only after retrieving the files.